# If real and imaginary part of a matrix are invertible then the matrix itself is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, complex-numbers, determinant

Since invertibility means that the determinant is non-zero, we can rewrite the statement above as following:

Let $ M \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ then:

$$\det(\Re(M)) \neq 0 \wedge   \det(\Im(M)) \neq 0  \Longrightarrow \det(M) \neq 0$$

I didn't manage to find a counterexample, but then I remembered that I could prove the statement by proving it's negation wrong:

Let $ M \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ then:

$$\det(\Re(M)) = 0 \vee   \det(\Im(M)) = 0 \Longrightarrow \det(M) = 0$$

And this is obviously false, if you just consider real invertible matrices as a counterexample. Which means that the original statement is true.

Proving it this way feels a bit too easy. Is the proof correct? Are there other ways to prove this?

Comment: You did the [Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic)) instead of the negation.

Comment: Ok, I see. So I've proven that the inverse of the original statement is false, therefore the original statement is also false.

Comment: No. The inverse of a statement is equivalent to the converse of the statement. The falsity of the second statement only means that the converse of the first statement is not true, i.e., when $M$ is invertible, the real part and the imaginary parts of $M$ are not necessarily invertible.

Comment: Inverse is an unfortunate terminology. Sounds too much like it should be equivalent to negation. But it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. E.g. $X=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}$ and $Y=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ are invertible, but
$$
X+iY=\pmatrix{1&i\\ i&-1}=\pmatrix{1\\ i}\pmatrix{1& i}
$$
is singular.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on what went wrong with my proof?

Comment: @haifisch123 Your second statement is not the negation of the first. The negation of $p\to q$ is $p\,\wedge\sim q$.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is not correct. The negation of $P \implies Q$ is $P \land \neg Q$. Applying this to your case, we find that the negation of

$$\det(\Re(M)) \neq 0 \wedge   \det(\Im(M)) \neq 0  \Longrightarrow \det(M) \neq 0$$

is

$$\det(\Re(M)) \neq 0 \wedge   \det(\Im(M)) \neq 0  \wedge \det(M) = 0.$$